# Django multi-valued search bar

Tags: python, html, django

For my website I am trying to design a search bar that will filter more than one attributes of a certain class, e.g. name and telephone.
However, I don't know how to get multiple values from one page in python. I have made many attempts but all have faied.
I am posting the most recent (which also doesn't work). I could really use some help.

```
def search(request):
errors = []
if 'q1' in request.GET:
    q1 = request.GET['q1']
if 'q2' in request.GET:
        q2 = request.GET['q2']
    if not (q1 or q2):
        errors.append('Enter a search term.')
    elif ((len(q1) > 20) or (len(q2) > 20)):
        errors.append('Please enter at most 20 characters.')
    elif q1 and (not q2):
        hotels = Hotel.objects.filter(name__icontains=q1)
        return render(request, 'company/search_results.html', {'hotels': hotels, 'query': q1})
    elif ((not q1) and q2):
        hotels = Hotel.objects.filter(street__icontains=q2)
        return render(request, 'company/search_results.html', {'hotels': hotels, 'query': q2})
    else:
    names = Hotel.objects.filter(name__icontains=q1)
        streets = Hotel.objects.filter(street__icontains=q2)
    hotels = (names and streets)
        return render(request, 'company/search_results.html', {'hotels': hotels, 'query': (q1 or q2)})
return render(request, 'company/search_form.html',
    {'errors': errors})
```

I also post part of the the html code where i get the input.

```
<table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="q1"></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>telephone:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="q2"></td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
    <form action="/company/search/" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code. First I used `get()` to fetch the parameters so you don't need to use the if in request.GET. Next I made use of [chaining QuerySet filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters). Finally, I have it returning both q1 and q2 to the template. It doesn't make sense to only return a query when you can enter both.

```
def search(request):
    errors = []
    q1 = request.GET.get('q1')
    q2 = request.GET.get('q2')
    if not (q1 or q2):
        errors.append('Enter a search term.')
    elif ((len(q1) > 20) or (len(q2) > 20)):
        errors.append('Please enter at most 20 characters.')
    else:
        hotels = Hotel.objects.all()
        if q1:
            hotels = hotels.filter(name__icontains=q1)
        if q2:
            hotels = hotels.filter(street__icontains=q2)
    return render(request, 'company/search_results.html', {'hotels': hotels, 'q1': q1, 'q2': q2, 'errors': errors})
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone cares i find the following mistake on my code:

the input should be **inside** the form that specifies the "action"

plus i fixed my code so i am posting it too:

```
def search(request):
errors = []
q1 = None
q2 = None
if 'name' in request.GET:
    q1 = request.GET['name']
if 'telephone' in request.GET:  
    q2 = request.GET['telephone']
if not (q1 or q2):
        errors.append('Enter a search term.')
elif q1 and (not q2):
        hotels = Hotel.objects.filter(name__icontains=q1)
        return render(request, 'company/search_results.html', {'hotels': hotels, 'query': q1})
elif ((not q1) and q2):
        hotels = Hotel.objects.filter(number__icontains=q2)
        return render(request, 'company/search_results.html', {'hotels': hotels, 'query': q2})
else:
    names = Hotel.objects.filter(name__icontains=q1)
        streets = Hotel.objects.filter(number__icontains=q2)
    hotels = (names and streets)
        return render(request, 'company/search_results.html', {'hotels': hotels, 'query': (q1 or q2)})
return render(request, 'company/search_form.html',
    {'errors': errors})
```